# WSDL editor / compiler for linux

Tags: xml, wsdl, editor

I have searched the web clean and could not find a solution for my problem:

I am looking for open source software / plugin to edit WSDL (XML based) documents (WSDL compiler / editor).
I am using Linux Mint 12.

Can anyone please help me find any wsdl software?

Comment: What do you want to compile the wsdl into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has a wsdl editor

http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Introduction_to_the_WSDL_Editor

Answer (score 1):

WSDL is XML, so you could certainly use an XML Editor like [XML Copy Editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/), or somethine based on Eclipse like [Rinzo](http://editorxml.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a support for XML editing and validation, see [XML Validation Tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/XMLValidation/XMLValidationTutorial.html). No need to install any extra plugins.